# Catching a ClassCastException in Try/Catch (unit tests)

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm writing a reference based implementation of a queue and the documentation for a queue says that the offer() method throws a ClassCastException. But I'm not sure how I would test for that in a unit test.

I know to trigger it you have to cast some object from String to Integer or Integer to String for example, but I'm not sure how to put that into a try/catch block. Would I use an assertNotEquals statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a test just to trigger this Exception and make sure it is thrown:

```
@Test(expected=ClassCastException.class)
public void testClassCastExceptionException() {
    // Your test here
}
```

Do not use `try catch` in a Unit test, unless you want to ignore the Exception explicitly.

This test above will pass only if the Exception is thrown.